# How to fixed this dependence problems

Tags: angular, typescript

I update my angular and my angular project version to angular 7. But... When I try to run I have this problem:

```
Package "@angular/compiler-cli" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires ">=3.1.1 <3.2", would install "3.2.2").
Incompatible peer dependencies found. See above.
```

how I can fixed it? If is possible install a version of angular/compiler-cli supported typescript 3.2.2

Answer (score 5):

I've got the same issue and the next steps helped me to fix it:

1. To the `package.json` file at the `devDependencies` add the next row `"typescript": "^3.1.6"`
2. Run `ng update @angular/cli` or `ng update --all`
3. Now when you'll run `ng serve` will get the next error `ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.1.1 and <3.2.0 but 3.2.2 was found instead.`
4. To fix this install the same typescript version 3.1.6 
   with npm `npm i typescript@3.1.6 --save-dev --save-exact` or yarn `yarn add typescript@3.1.6 --save-dev`

Now when you run `ng serve` everything should work fine and angular cli will be updated

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question and the proposed solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this as well just run

```
    ng update
```

to see when needs to be updated. for me I got the following output

```
  We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:

  Name                               Version                  Command to update
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @angular/cli                       7.0.6 -> 7.1.3           ng update @angular/cli
  @angular/core                      7.0.4 -> 7.1.3           ng update @angular/core
```

so I ran what it recommends

```
   ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

also make sure to use npm install typescript to match typescript with the version that is being requested

if you run ng update again it should tell you everything is up to date

Comment: You are not resolving the issue doing that, just silencing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly says that typescript dependency stated in your package.json would install version 3.2.2 which is not supported by compiler-cli 7.x package of angular that you're trying to install. It means that versions should be aligned and typescript version should be limited in the package.json to those that are specified in the error text.

Comment: Actually, if you have something like `typescript 3.1.1` in your `package.json`, you will get the complaint also: that's because `ng update --all` with try to replace with `typescript 3.2.2` and will see it conflicts with `@angular/compiler-cli`

Comment: @Mic - exactly, this is why my answer says "versions should be aligned and **typescript version should be limited in the package.json** to those that are specified in the error text". In this case `npm update` will not try to update it beyond max version that's specified in the package.json.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use @angular/cli to run angular update.

```
 ng update  # will display all updates that need to be done
 ng update --all # use it at your own risk ;-)
```

then packages versions will be up to date with the one supported by angular, which might not be the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's walk through the situation:

You have `@angular/complier-cli` that depends on `typescript < 3.2.0`. But you must also have a mention of `typescript` in your `packages.json`.

When `ng update --all` sees `typescript` module, it tries to update it to latest version: 3.2.2. But it sees it would conflict with `@angular/compiler-cli` expectations.

So it warns you that you cannot update all packages to last version... until `compiler-cli` is updated to be compatible with latests `typescript` version.

The easiest way to solve this is thus to "block" typescript to the correct version, for example put "typescript": "3.1.1" in your packages.json, and it will solve the warning.